# Vtiger6..One Field with Another Module

Tags: customization, vtiger

I have a field named as Vendor in Products. I want to like this Vendor field with Vendors module so that It gives me list of vendors where I can add and select appropriate one.

How will I do it with code .. Where Will I place relations and module code.. In products.php or where?

or Can it be done through Vtiger UI?

Plz Guide

Thanks..

Comment: Please have look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858958/vtiger-how-to-use-module-field-in-another-module/14434991#14434991

Comment: Thx @Salim So nice of you